# Connection string to remote sql server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, connection

I have a web application - that I open in VS and run successfully on my PC.

On a new netbook, I have installed VS 2008 Professional with SP1 and turned on IIS features. Using the exact same solution and code (copied from PC) it will not connect to the database server on the netbook. I do not have SQL server installed on the netbook as the database being used is remote.

The database is located on a hosting provider's database server. So remote connections on the db server is of course enabled. The connection string works when running the web application on VS on my PC so I assume all is OK with the database server configuration and it is something to do with the setup on the netbook.

the error is as such...

> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the netbook, does VS2008 have access to the internet/network?

Are you accessing the sqlserver via IP or by a network name?

Comment: My netbook has access to the internet through a home network, I assume this means VS also has access? I am accessing via network name i.e., mssqldb1.provider.net.nz (ficticious name there obviously but same format).

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like that the netbook may not have connection privileges to the SQL server.  Since you are using the exact same code that works on a desktop that can connect, I assume that the connection string is correct. I would start looking at firewall settings and software permissions (specifically, the exceptions tab in Windows Firewall).

Comment: Closest answer here - turns out the hosting company just took 15 days to open the port up to my IP from the server. Thanks so much anyways.

Comment: Ouch, that sucks. Glad to see that you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the error message you're seeing. On the SQL Server machine, you need to start SQL Server Configuration Manager and enable remote connections via TCP/IP.

Comment: remote connections is enabled on the sql server machine, its a database server provided bny a hosting company and the connection string runs fine when running the web app via my PC. Thats why I think it may be something to do with my netbook settings. Added a new paragraph (the third one) for clarification

Comment: It's not the fact that you don't have SQL server installed on the netbook; if it were, that would mean that every PC/netbook/whatever on the planet would have to have SQL Server installed on it to access a SQL Server DB. As I said, it's in the configuration or your connection string; that's clearly what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

By deafult, the remote connection of sql server is **disable**.
You need to enabled that in the sql server configuration.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, are you referring to the sql server configuration on the database server itself? Check out the third paragraph I've added for clarification

Answer (score 1):

You should go into Sql Server Configuration Manager and make sure Named Pipes is enabled.

Comment: Thanks, are you referring to the sql server configuration on the database server itself? Check out the third paragraph I've added for clarification.

Comment: No, I was referring to the configuration on the Netbook itself. A new Netbook using Windows 7 Starter Edition will typically come with SQL Server installed on it.

Comment: If that doesn't work you might want to check the firewall settings, or make sure that other Windows services are enabled.